# Time to eat then

Tags: mathematics, visual

Let the picture speak for itself. Only 1 option is correct. Give a clear explanation as to why.
So... Which one is it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think the answer is

> D

Reasoning

> The first picture shows the time **1:09**.
>  I think we then need to interpret the middle shapes as movements of the minute hand around the clock. In particular, we move it through the common angle of each shape the number of times specified in the centre of the shape.
>  In particular,
>  Triangle, 4 = Move minute hand $60^o$, four times $\rightarrow$ time is now **1:49**.
>  Hexagon, 2 = Move minute hand $120^o$, twice $\rightarrow$ time is now **2:29**.
>  Square, 3 = Move minute hand $90^o$, three times $\rightarrow$ time is now **3:14**.
>  So the end time is **3:14** which looks like the approximation to $\pi$, $3.14$ and that is why I choose the **pie**, image D.

Comment: This is correct :)

Comment: Lol, that's what I guessed too.  Just from the tags "mathematics".